# How to get the first value from a sorted table into a measure?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a DAX table with 2 columns RANK and VALUE. I need a measure that returns the VALUE for the row where RANK is the lowest.

Solution needs to be efficient as table has tens of millions of rows with distinct values in column VALUE.

I have tried using TOPN, but this returns a table, not a single value.
I have tried using MIN, but this would return the lowest VALUE, not the VALUE with the lowest RANK
I cannot use LOOKUPVALUE because in my real world example, the table has many more columns than those 2, and some of those columns would have filters applied to them by the client application, and obviously I don't know those filters at design time.

```
VALUE        RANK     MANY_MORE_COLUMNS ...
100          1        ...
200          2        ...
50           3        ...
```

In this case, I would need the value 100 to be returned, because lowest RANK is 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( Table[VALUE] ),
    FILTER ( Table, Table[RANK] = MIN ( Table[RANK] ) )
)
```

The FILTER function filters 'Table' to the row with the lowest RANK. MAX(Table[VALUE]) then returns the VALUE in that row. Allthough there is only one row, you need to use a function here that returns a scalar value (MAX in this case). The CALCULATE function expects a scalar value as an argument here.

Comment: Excellent!  I was struggling with this problem.